# xpath in the importXML: //comment() vs //*/comment()

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Why I'm geting [different results with xpath in the importXML](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Z3xybq_eYQvjn2-UBOomgeJxFrrsFoXKzF9yZSeASM/edit#gid=257685615)

```
//comment() vs //*/comment()
```

Question maybe stupid, but I'm not getting any results at all (#N/A) with `//comment()`.

This is probably question for general case:

```
//node vs //*/node
```

Comment: Huh?  And you _are_ getting results with `//*/comment()`?  I would expect if `//comment()` comes up empty then the other version would also be empty.

Comment: @Tim-Biegeleisen g.sh** full of surprises? link to sandbox g.spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Z3xybq_eYQvjn2-UBOomgeJxFrrsFoXKzF9yZSeASM/edit#gid=257685615

Comment: I'm getting the same results for both expressions... Check again thoroughly

Comment: @Andersson Where - in the sandbox g.spreadsheet?

Comment: @AndriuZ , I mean on [provided page](https://www.varle.lt/plansetiniai-kompiuteriai/?sort=price&f.s-gamintojas=Lenovo&f.s-gamintojas=Samsung&f.s-gamintojas=Asus&f.s-gamintojas=Acer&f.s-gamintojas=Huawei&f.r.float-ekrano_istrizaine=9:9.99-&f.r.float-ekrano_istrizaine=10:10.99-&f.s-operacine_sistema=Android&f.s-4g_rysys=Yra&f.s-wi_fi=Yra)

Comment: @Andersson but my problem is with xpath in the importXML in the g.sh*, I understand, tha I can use another technique to scrap results, but...

Comment: I think this has to do with the way GS spreads out the results: if you use `//*`on that source you will see that Gs populates various cells and columns. If you only try to receive the root you just get a cell with some javascript.

Comment: @wp78de You mean if `//` GS is looking for `comment()` only in root ant not elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, if you only search the "root" it looks like it is only looking at the one cell/array element that contains JS - and therefore cannot find comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody else is coming up with a good answer, I add mine:

I **suspect** the problems stems from the **AJAX nature of the page** in question and the way the `IMPORTXML()` methods on Google Sheets operates.

Querying the document root and selection nodes using the XPath `/` gives us an intuition. Doing so returns a cell full of JavaScript but not the actual (HTML) source of the page. Using `//` results in the described loading error. It looks like it is only searching this one cell that contains the JS - and therefore cannot find comments (or any other child node) using the XPath query `//comment()`.

However, if we query `//*` some 100+ cells on the spreadsheet are populated with various page elements and source snippets (which is probably caused by some EOL or line-breaks in separate source files loaded into the page). So, that way all the parts of the page are loaded, including the comments. And thus, now we can load them using `//*/comment()` as discovered by you (`/*//comment()` works for me as well).

This behavior does not make sense (and is certainly not in line with XPath specifications) but it seems to be the way how GS's `IMPORTXML` method deals with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the XPath language definition, `//comment()` should find all comments anywhere in the document, while `//*/comment()` should find all comments that have an element as their parent: that is, all comments except those that have the document node as their parent.

So they aren't equivalent, but the second expression should return a subset of the results of the first expression.

Comment: I'm talking about the spec here. If a product behaves differently, then it's wrong. (And I've no idea what `#N/A` means).

Comment: @MichaelK This is correct in general, but not clear with g.sheets particularly.  If you bother to look into sandbox youl will find: #N/A is Error: Imported content is empty. - i.e. it's expected to receive XML content in both cases.

Comment: As I said, I was talking about the language spec. I can't comment if a particular implementation doesn't follow the spec.